# How can i use abp framework for marketplace project?

Tags: abp

I want to make an application like marketplace.And i want to use abp framework for adminpanel and services.So how can i customize abp aspnet core mvc webui as admin area in my project.Is this way mindfull ? what is your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Customization-User-Interface) for customizing UI.

Also there is a open-source UI template that is developed by community members. :)

https://github.com/realLiangshiwei/Lsw.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Stisla

Comment: Thanks for helping.
i am trying to do that,
xxxx.com/admin here works abp project 
and 
xxxx.com/products   like this url i want to use another public website project.
I mean there are 2 project;
1 of them for only admin users
1 of them for public users who came from organic search. and theese 2 project in same domain but reach them different urls.

Like using Areas in mvc but i didn't know how to do it with abp.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to use 2 different project with same domain. I do not suggest to use different project in one domain like `website.com/admin` and `product`. Why you don't try to move your `admin` project to a `subdomain`. So you can use your abp project under `admin.website.com` and your another project runs under `example.com`.